# Restoring deleted folder in archive PST

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a very weird issue, and I'm not sure if there is a solution.

I have a 1.8GB PST file that was created via Outlook 2010's Archive feature. It appears that the Inbox went missing, however calendar items are still there.

I used the scanpst.exe utility to "recover" the file, but this only recovers the calendar items. It shows 11 folders listed in the PST, but upon recovery I only see 5 folders (Calendar, Deleted Items, Journal, Tasks) which don't have any of the emails.

I used the MFCMAPI.exe tool to get a closer look. There is no hidden folder (via PR_ATTR_HIDDEN), and no "Inbox" folder exists anymore. The existing folders all seem to be gone. Additionally, there is no "Recoverable items" folder.

Is there any way that I can get all of the items from this PST, regardless of which folder they belonged to?

Comment: Have you tried just importing the whole `.pst` file? [Import Outlook items from an Outlook Data File (.pst)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Import-Outlook-items-from-an-Outlook-Data-File-pst-431a8e9a-f99f-4d5f-ae48-ded54b3440ac)

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I have. Outlook simply doesn't see the missing folders/files, yet the PST is still practically the same size as before.